# PostgreSQL database dump and Python's psycopg2 library

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Salute,

I have .sql file (Postgresql) which is a sql dump of the follwing format:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 9.0
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 11.1

(SET statements omitted for brevity)
--
-- Name: Auto_Inventory; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: Jeff
--

CREATE TABLE public.Auto_Inventory (....);

ALTER TABLE public.Auto_Inventory OWNER TO Jeff;

--
-- Data for Name: Auto_Inventory; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: Jeff_P
--

COPY public.Auto_Inventory (part, part_id, part_price($)) FROM stdin;
battery        013259     86
air_filter     069542     17
alternator     026354     239
\.
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

Questions (I am new to PostgreSQL):

Can this dump file be executed to print only that table to a csv ?
Can this be accomplished in python ?
I do not have user,pass,port to connect to the database, but let's assume it's public and I know only the name of this db, is a connection possible?

I tried the psycopg2 python library, and I obviously need to make a connection to the data base, but I only have the .sql file and no password/port information to authenticate the connection. All I would like to accomplish/find-out is the best way to print that table from this .sql file using python.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A dump file doesn't enable you to connect to an existing database unless you already know how to do that.  And if you could connect, you would just export from the database and so would not need the dump file at all.

You could set up a new database under your control, load the dump file to it, then re-extract the data using `COPY....with (format csv)`

Or, since your example doesn't show anything that needs special treatment, you could just delete the extra lines and then convert tabs to commas using your favorite text editor.  Or I guess python, if you really want to.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Could you explain in further details on setting up a new database? I would appreciate if you can provide references to creating the database and the command to loading the dump file and outputting the table only. I only have limited sql exposure through Bigquery. Thanks!